# How to call ERC 721 smart contract methods from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nft, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets, mint

I'm trying to create a simple nft minting website and I have my contract working properly but I'm having trouble implementing the actual minting process. So far my site only has the ability to let users connect to metamask but I can't figure out how to interact with a smart contract in js.

For reference, my site is a plain JS on the front and node on the back. I put together the smart contract on remix and have tested it thoroughly, I just need a way to access it from my website. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, I'm starting to lose my sanity a little lol.

Answer (score 1):

with ethers or web3js, you'll be able to interact with contracts from your frontend. if you're using plain javascript, you can use cdn links to import respective libraries.

shown below with ethersjs

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);

// read method
const tokenId = 1;
contract.tokenURI(tokenId)
  .then((uri) => console.log('token uri from contract', uri)
  .catch((err) => error(err));
    });

// write method sending ether along with transaction
const tx = await contract.mint(tokenUri, tokenId, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01') });

// wait for the transaction to be mined
await tx.wait()
```

similarly with web3js

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
// window.web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545); // or any other rpc provider
// window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address, options);   // options = {from: account, value: 100000 }

// smartcontract read method
contract.methods.tokenURI(1).call().then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

// write method
contract.methods.mint(tokenURI, tokenId).send({ from: web3.eth.defaultAccount }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

docs links:
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/